# Pass command line arguments to another command in bash

Tags: linux, node.js, bash

I have a program which takes some command line arguments.

It's executed like this:

```
user@home $ node server.js SOME ARGUMENTS -p PORT -t THEME OTHER STUFF
```

Now I want to make a executable launcher for it:

```
#!/bin/bash

node server.js ARGUMENTS GIVEN FROM COMMAND LINE
```

How to do this?

I want to pass the same arguments to the command (without knowing how many and what they will be).

Is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `$@` variable in double quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash

node server.js "$@"
```

This will provide all the arguments passed on the command line and protect spaces that could appear in them. If you don't use quotes, an argument like `"foo bar"` (that is, a single argument whose string value has a space in it) passed to your script will be passed to `node` as two arguments. From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters):

> When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ….

In light of the other answer, edited to add: I fail to see why you'd want to use `$*` at all. Execute the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Quoted:"
for arg in "$*"; do
    echo $arg
done

echo "Unquoted:"
for arg in $*; do
    echo $arg
done
```

With, the following (assuming your file is saved as `script` and is executable):

```
$ script "a b" c
```

You'll get:

```
Quoted:
a b c
Unquoted:
a
b
c
```

Your user meant to pass two arguments: `a b`, and `c`. The "Quoted" case processes it as *one* argument: `a b c`. The "Unquoted" case processes it as 3 arguments: `a`, `b` and `c`. You'll have unhappy users.

Comment: I mentioned `$*` because it's often used by bash beginners instead of `$@`.

Comment: The *In light of the other answer* part is a kinda confusing (not really part of an answer), but I'll give this to you since you came earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you want, probably using `$@`:

```
#!/bin/bash
node server.js "$@"
```

(Probably with quotes)

The thing to keep in mind is how arguments with e.g. spaces are handled. In this respect, `$*` and `$@` behave differently:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo '$@:'
for arg in "$@"; do
  echo $arg
done

echo '$*:'
for arg in "$*"; do
  echo $arg
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh a "b c"
$@:
a
b c
$*:
a b c
```